# Have all settings back on Control Panel Win10

Tags: windows, windows-10, control-panel

So I've just broke all UWP apps on the system (hopefully was only that...), and I really don't want to format this thing again... I'm still trying to fix it with the help of Google, but in any case...

Would anyone know if there's ANY way to restore all the settings on the Control Panel? All those that were there on Windows 7, for example. At minimum the ones from 8/8.1 (would be an improvement already). They moved various to the Settings app, which I can't access at the moment (anymore on this installation?). So if I could go back to always use the Control Panel, that would be amazingly easier. The only UWP app I use aside from Settings is the Camera, but I can live perfectly well without it (I've another app which I used on Windows 7 and I installed it here too, so I'm good without the UWP one).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any clues!

EDIT: Not even the new Start Menu is working (I use StartIsBack, so I wasn't noticing). Would be really nice to have everything back on Control Panel... Network popup gone too... At least Sound and Battery are here because I'm using Win32 ones. This is going well hahaha.

**UPDATE:** So I fixed this thing ([Entire UWP system not working on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1602962/entire-uwp-system-not-working-on-windows-10)). UWP apps are working again (partially reinstalled Windows with the Keep Everything option and I got it back working). Now it's just my curiosity. Is this possible? (the main question)

Comment: I suggest fixing it properly instead. You’ll get problems with Windows updates in 6-18 months otherwise.

Comment: Ah about that don't really worry much about the updates. I have LTSC edition installed. Didn't want that exact problem, so I installed this one... No forced upgrades anymore.

Comment: How did you broke the UWP apps? For common start menu issue like missing store app and so on, they could be recovered by re-register windows app command.
Would it be problem related to StartIsBack?

Comment: By changing custom themes. Not sure what made the UWP system break though. But it happened in the middle of changing custom themes. I couldn't even see the login screen. Only entering the password various times so I knew it would login. Safe Mode with Networking didn't work also... (broke it well this time XD). I love CMD sometimes haha, as it helped me fix it... At most this could have to do with AeroGlass for Win8.1+, which changes the themes, but I'm not sure, because I may have messed it up.