# Entire UWP system not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop-repair, repair, uwp

(I hope the title is correct. I'm no Windows UWP developer, but nothing works, so I guess their UWP system is gone here, but correct me if I'm wrong, please)

So I messed up UWP..... Not sure how though, but was related to installing custom themes. When I installed the theme, the entire system crashed partially. I would continue to hear the music I had playing, but my main screen went black (back light still On though, just color black) and my secondary screen went partially black, and the rest was a frozen "frame" of a video I was watching there. Then I rebooted the computer and tried to uninstall the program. Just wanted to uninstall it right away before it would crash again. It was said to change to the default theme before uninstalling or I wouldn't be able to login, but I didn't read in time and just clicked Uninstall.... --> stupid, I know. Hopefully this gives some hint of what may have happened?

Anyways, NOTHING related to UWP works on this thing. No Start Menu, or battery/clock/network flyouts, Settings app, Store app, whatever related to UWP (I'm using StartIsBack and Win32 flyouts for battery and clock, so I've that as a workaround - no Win32 flyout for Network though..... cool).

I even tried reinstalling the Store app, but it does nothing, so I guess reinstalling any other UWP apps won't do anything.

If I open the Settings app, it will say "Class not registered". Windows Explorer says Unknown Hard Error on Safe Mode (before it didn't say anything).

WSReset.exe returns ms-windows-store:PurgeCaches Error in file system (-2018374635), if that helps.

I already did some things to try to fix this, but I think I'll only mention the last one, which I believe redid everything I had already done, because I'm talking of a program of Windows repairs --> Tweaking.com. Executed all repairs, and chose the option to reset the Microsoft Store. Nothing worked so far. Only managed to put the taskbar appearing while on full screen with VLC and Edge, so useful having done this, as I can't change any settings because I can't access the damn Settings app...

I can't format this until at least Christmas and I need it working decently... (even on Christmas I'm not sure because I'll have much to do). And anyways I hate formatting computers.... Infinity to have everything ready again and have to reput everything here. Hopefully there's a solution without having to format the computer...

Any ideas on how to fix the UWP system on this thing????? I've tried some ideas, but I think none are meant to repair a completely not working UWP system.... ANY (but I mean ***ANY***) ideas are greatly welcomed and thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Not even Show Desktop button works or Win+D XD. Christ, what I did on this thing..... Are such small things on Windows 10 that dependent on UWP...? (unless I broke more than only UWP and have no idea...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you can open a browser window.

Run a Windows 10 Repair Install. This is not format and install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Assuming Keep Everything works, you can be done in a couple of hours.

If Keep Everything does not correct the issue, then do the Repair again and just Keep Data.  This means re-installing your apps, so let us hope Keep Everything works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But what if I say I have LTSC edition installed....? haha. Should I still use that one or another one? (Or there's none for LTSC?) But yeah, I can do everything on the computer (I'm writing this on it). Except using any UWP things - which I never do, except with Settings and the Network taskbar flyout, which I'm starting to miss a bit... hahaha.

Comment: Repair should still work, although Repair keeps versions up to date.  If you have the ISO for the LTSC, run setup on that and it may keep the same version.

Comment: @DADi590 - You will want to use an ISO for the same Windows 10 version you have installed.  If you use an ISO for a different version, and you have LTSC, then all sorts of weird things might happen.  However, are you sure actually have LTSC installed, because it doesn't come with the Windows Store installed out of the box

Comment: Hmm I'll try this when I can then. Hopefully it won't break anything more... I don't have another computer here to fix this one in case this one breaks completely (like I thought I had done hours ago). Thanks for the suggestion. And yes, I have LTSC. The Store I installed it manually haha (https://github.com/kkkgo/LTSC-Add-MicrosoftStore). And I'll use the exact same ISO I used (stored it, as I always do).

Comment: I'll start praying haha. Without a working phone and a working computer it's gonna be hard to deliver some works I gotta deliver hahaha. Let's see what happens.... I made some modifications to the system to have it look really much like Windows 7, so I hope that won't break the installation. In any case, thank you for the suggestion again!

Comment: I had never used that option. Even more with modifications on the system. One more point to the Windows I don't like, as I believe this is not possible on Windows 7 (if it is and I didn't know, I take back the point xD). Anyways haha. Thank you both!!! The computer is back working. Now I just can't install apps from the Store (I think I also broke the Store because I can't see it installed, but that's MEGA secondary). UWP apps are working again (for some reason the Camera one blinks the camera light, but ok xD). Thank you again! I thought it would be registry hacks or whatever, but was easier.

Comment: Thank you for the update and I am glad your computer is working.